# Not able to get results with SAGA's regression tools

Tags: qgis, saga

I'm trying to find in QGIS an analogous tool to ArcGIS's "Ordinary Least Squares". The tool takes in a shapefile, where the dependent variable and independent variables are all fields in the same shapefile. The tool runs OLS and returns a shapefile with the same features as the original, with fields for fitted values and residuals.

I've been exploring with SAGA, but for some reason I can't get results. I looked at "Multiple Linear Regression (Shapes)" and it seems the tools is not correctly configured. I'm trying to use the Multiple Linear Regression (Shapes) , but nothing comes out (error; the layers were not correctly generated). I tried with my layer of point and polygons. The attribute table has real numbers and percentages (decimals (doble) ej. 1,34 % ; 35,00 %).

I would love to see a 'step by step' tutorial to explore different options with regressions (including Geographically Weighted Regressions).

saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/7.8.0/statistics_regression_13.html